# Problem loop and computation between different columns on a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, if-statement

Here is my problem,

I have this DataFrame:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2017-05-19','2017-05-22','2017-05-23','2017-05-24','2017-05-25','2017-05-26','2017-05-29'],
                 'A':[153,152,153,155,153,154,155],
                 'B':[139,137,141,141.5,141.8,142.1,142.06],})

df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('Date')
```

My goal was to create another DataFrame named `df_end` where I will have a column named "total" corresponding to the total number of column of `df` (which is 2) and two column A and B that will take the value "1" if the 1 day rolling mean is > the 2 days rolling mean

Here is the code that I wrote :

```
def test(dataframe):
    df_init=(dataframe*0).assign(total=0)
    df_end=(dataframe*0).assign(total=0)
    
    df_init.iloc[0,df_init.columns.get_loc('total')]=2
    df_end.iloc[0,df_end.columns.get_loc('total')]=2
    
    rolling_2D=dataframe.rolling(2).mean().fillna(0)
    rolling_1D=dataframe.rolling(1).mean().fillna(0)
    
    calendar=pd.Series(df_init.index)[1:]
    
    for date in calendar:
        for cols in dataframe:
            prev_date=df_init.index[df_init.index<date][-1] 
            df_init.loc[date,:]=df_end.loc[prev_date,:] #df_init takes the value of df_end on the previous date
            
            
            M=2 #number of columns different from the column 'total'
            count = (df_init.loc[date,dataframe.columns]!=0).sum() #this will be used to compute the weight
            
            #Weight
            if count != M:
                weight = 1/(M-count)
            else:
                weight = 1
            
            #Repartition between different columns 
            repartition = df_init.loc[date,cols]+df_init.loc[date,'total']*weight
            
            #Conditions
            if rolling_1D.loc[date,cols] > rolling_2D.loc[date,cols] and df_init.loc[date,cols]==0:
                df_end.loc[date,cols]=repartition
                df_end.loc[date,'total']=df_init.loc[date,'total'] - df_end.loc[date,cols]
            
            elif rolling_1D.loc[date,cols] > rolling_2D.loc[date,cols] and df_init.loc[date,cols]!=0:
                df_end.loc[date,cols]=df_init.loc[date,cols]
                df_end.loc[date,'total']=df_init.loc[date,'total']
            
            else:
                df_end.loc[date,cols]=0
                df_end.loc[date,'total']=df_init.loc[date,cols]+df_init.loc[date,'total']
    
    return df_end
```

When I return df_end this is what I have:

```
            A     B    total
Date            
2017-05-19  0.0  0.0    2.0
2017-05-22  0.0  0.0    2.0
2017-05-23  1.0  1.0    1.0
2017-05-24  1.0  1.0    1.0
2017-05-25  0.0  1.0    1.0
2017-05-26  1.0  1.0    1.0
2017-05-29  1.0  0.0    2.0
```

As you can see, my program take into account the column B only and I don't know where is my mistake.

The result that I am looking for is:

```
            A     B    total
Date            
2017-05-19  0.0  0.0    2.0
2017-05-22  0.0  0.0    2.0
2017-05-23  1.0  1.0    0.0
2017-05-24  1.0  1.0    0.0
2017-05-25  0.0  1.0    1.0
2017-05-26  1.0  1.0    0.0
2017-05-29  1.0  0.0    1.0
```

I know that I am almost done with this code and I'm stuck with this problem.

Do you have any idea where my problem could be?

Thank you so much for the help

Comment: I'm not sure I undersand the end result you're trying to get. Each column should be 1 if the rolling mean for the last 2 rows is larger than the rolling mean for the last 1 row (which is the row itself)?

Comment: Hi @Roy2012, thank you for the answer. Let's say that we have 2 units (which are on the column 'total' at the beginning) and we put 1 unit on one column if the rolling mean of the last 1 row (which is the row itself) is larger than the rolling mean of the last 2 rows, that's why the column total increase or decrease if the condition is true or not. I thank you for looking at my post and don't hesitate to tell if something is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple way to do that:

```
new_df = (df.rolling(1).mean() > df.rolling(2).mean()).astype(int)
new_df["total"] = 2 - new_df.sum(axis=1)
print(new_df)
```

The output is:

```
            A  B  total
Date                   
2017-05-19  0  0      2
2017-05-22  0  0      2
2017-05-23  1  1      0
2017-05-24  1  1      0
2017-05-25  0  1      1
2017-05-26  1  1      0
2017-05-29  1  0      1
```

Comment: I'm always doing things more complicated than it should be lol. Thank you so much for the help it's perfect this way!